# Creating a heat map in a circle according to positions on x and y axes

Tags: plotting, graphics, map

I would appreciate advice on writing code.

I need to draw a heat map according to positions, it indicates object trajectory so the order is matter.

The positions are saved in a nested list.
An inner list contains a track of a single repetition.

I want to color red in areas where the density of locations is greater and in blue where the density is lower, dark blue if there is no presence at all.

For example, use ListLinePlot created the image:[image: ][1]]

You can see that the density increases in the center and in the circumference of the circle I added.
I would appreciate advice on how to color relevant areas in this list (sorry for the length, and the list is partial because there is no space, for the full-length press [the link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QJc6fbhkQ4yVSB9dV7gp7Sg9LCwcoOJj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103044649471980772342&rtpof=true&sd=true)).

```
data = {{{12., 10.4}, {12.3, 12.7}, {12.8, 15.}, {13.6, 17.3}, {14.8, 19.3}, {16.2, 21.1}, {17.9, 23.2}, {19.7, 24.7}, {21.8, 25.8}, {23.9, 26.5}, {25.9, 27.1}, {27.8, 27.7}, {29.2, 28.5}, {29.9, 29.2}, {30., 29.6}, {30.2, 29.9}, {30.6, 30.3}, {31.1, 30.9}, {31.5, 31.5}, {31.9, 31.3}, {31.9, 31.4}, {31.6, 31.6}, {31.7, 32.}, {32., 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.3, 32.2}, {32.5, 32.2}, {32.9, 32.6}, {33.2, 32.8}, {33.2, 32.5}, {33., 32.}, {32.6, 31.6}, {32.2, 31.3}, {31.9, 31.}, {31.3, 30.7}, {30.8, 30.7}, {30.1, 30.8}, {29.2, 30.9}, {28., 30.8}, {26.6, 30.7}, {25.1, 30.5}, {23.2, 30.3}, {21.3, 30.3}, {19.5, 30.7}, {18., 31.1}, {16.6, 31.7}, {15.9, 32.3}, {14.9, 33.4}, {14., 34.7}, {13.1, 35.8}, {12.2, 36.8}, {11.1, 37.9}, {9.9, 38.9}, {8.5, 40.}, {6.9, 40.9}, {5.2, 41.8}, {3.8, 42.9}, {2.8, 43.5}, {1.8, 43.8}, {1., 44.3}, {0.6, 45.1}, {0.5, 45.7}, {0.5, 46.1}, {0.5, 46.}, {0.3, 46.1}, {0.2, 46.1}, {0.4, 46.2}, {0.3, 46.3}, {0.3, 46.3}, {0.2, 46.4}, {0.1, 46.3}, {0.3, 46.3}, {0., 46.8}, {-0.1, 46.8}, {0., 46.8}, {0., 46.5}, {-0.1, 46.9}, {-0.1, 46.9}, {-0.2, 46.6}, {-0.1, 46.2}, {-0.2, 46.5}, {-0.3, 46.5}, {-0.1, 45.9}, {-0.1, 45.9}, {-0.3, 46.1}, {-0.3, 46.1}, {-0.3, 46.1}, {-0.3, 46.}, {-0.3, 46.2}, {-0.3, 46.2}, {-0.2, 46.2}, {-0.4, 46.3}, {-0.4, 46.1}, {-0.5, 46.2}, {-0.3, 46.1}, {-0.3, 46.1}, {-0.7, 46.5}, {-0.7, 46.5}, {-0.8, 46.5}, {-0.8, 46.6}, {-0.9, 46.4}, {-1., 46.3}, {-0.8, 46.4}, {-0.8, 46.4}, {-0.8, 46.4}, {-0.8, 46.8}, {-0.9, 46.6}, {-1.1, 46.3}, {-1.5, 46.5}, {-1.9, 46.5}, {-2.2, 46.6}, {-2.5, 46.7}, {-2.9, 46.3}, {-3.4, 45.7}, {-4., 45.3}, {-4.5, 45.}, {-5., 44.5}, {-5.3, 43.8}, {-5.6, 43.}, {-6.3, 42.2}, {-7.3, 41.4}, {-8.4, 40.5}, {-10., 39.9}, {-11.3, 39.3}, {-12.9, 38.9}, {-14.3, 38.}, {-15.8, 37.3}, {-17.6, 36.6}, {-19.6, 36.1}, {-21.5, 35.8}, {-23.4, 35.4}, {-25.4, 34.9}, {-27., 34.3}, {-28.3, 33.7}, {-29.5, 33.3}, {-30.5, 33.3}, {-31., 33.2}, {-31.4, 33.3}, {-32., 33.7}, {-32.2, 33.8}, {-32.4, 33.9}, {-32.6, 33.6}, {-32.5, 32.9}, {-32.5, 32.9}, {-33., 33.1}, {-33., 33.1}, {-32.8, 33.3}, {-32.4, 33.2}, {-32.6, 33.2}, {-32.4, 33.2}, {-32.7, 33.2}, {-33.2, 33.4}, {-33.2, 33.4}, {-33.3, 33.4}, {-32.9, 33.2}, {-32.8, 33.1}, {-33., 33.1}, {-33.1, 33.4}, {-33.2, 33.2}, {-33.2, 33.2}, {-32.9, 33.5}, {-32.8, 33.5}, {-32.9, 33.5}, {-33.3, 33.}, {-33.3, 33.}, {-33.1, 32.8}, {-33.1, 32.7}, {-33.1, 32.4}, {-33.1, 32.3}, {-33., 32.5}, {-33.3, 32.6}, {-33.2, 32.4}, {-33.2, 32.4}, {-33.3, 32.5}, {-33.3, 32.5}, {-33.7, 32.7}, {-33.9, 32.9}, {-33.9, 32.8}, {-33.8, 32.7}, {-33.9, 33.}, {-34.8, 33.2}, {-35.5, 33.}, {-35.5, 32.5}, {-36., 31.8}, {-36.5, 31.2}, {-37.1, 30.8}, {-37.5, 30.6}, {-38., 29.4}, {-38.8, 28.6}, {-39.8, 27.9}, {-40.4, 25.9}, {-40.4, 24.2}, {-40.2, 22.3}, {-40., 20.4}, {-39.9, 18.6}, {-40.1, 16.5}, {-40.4, 14.6}, {-40.8, 12.5}, {-41., 10.4}, {-41.6, 8.02}, {-41.8, 6.19}, {-42., 4.62}, {-42.5, 3.06}, {-43.2, 1.7}, {-43.9, 1.01}, {-44.2, 0.481}, {-44.4, 0.572}, {-44.5, 1.06}, {-44.7, 1.87}, {-43.5, 3.}, {-42.9, 4.48}, {-41.7, 6.25}, {-40.2, 8.36}, {-38.8, 10.6}, {-37.3, 12.9}, {-35.5, 15.}, {-33.7, 16.9}, {-32.1, 18.9}, {-31., 21.}, {-30.1, 22.9}, {-29.1, 24.5}, {-28.1, 25.8}, {-27.1, 27.}, {-26.3, 28.}, {-25.5, 29.}, {-24.7, 29.7}, {-23.4, 30.5}, {-22.7, 31.2}, {-22.1, 32.}, {-21.4, 32.5}, {-21., 33.3}, {-20.5, 33.9}, {-19.9, 34.}, {-19.2, 34.1}, {-18.3, 33.9}, {-17.5, 33.6}, {-17., 33.4}, {-16.7, 33.3}, {-16.3, 33.3}, {-16., 33.4}, {-15.6, 33.3}, {-15.1, 33.1}, {-14.7, 33.1}, {-14.3, 33.5}, {-13.7, 33.9}, {-12.9, 34.2}, {-12.1, 34.8}, {-11.1, 35.3}, {-10., 35.9}, {-9., 36.7}, {-8.1, 37.6}, {-7.2, 38.6}, {-6.3, 39.5}, {-5.4, 40.1}, {-4.8, 40.5}, {-4.4, 40.7}, {-4., 41.1}, {-3.8, 41.6}, {-3.7, 42.4}, {-3.7, 42.9}, {-3.4, 43.2}, {-2.9, 43.6}, {-2.5, 44.3}, {-2.2, 44.9}, {-1.8, 45.3}, {-1.6, 45.8}, {-1.5, 45.9}, {-1.5, 46.}, {-1.4, 46.1}, {-1.3, 46.2}, {-1.2, 46.3}, {-1.1, 46.3}, {-1.2, 46.3}, {-1.6, 45.8}, {-1.2, 45.4}, {-1.2, 45.4}, {-1.1, 45.1}, {-0.8, 45.8}, {-1., 45.7}, {-0.6, 45.3}, {0.2, 45.2}, {1.1, 44.6}, {2.1, 44.1}, {3.3, 44.2}, {4.6, 43.9}, {5.9, 43.4}, {7.3, 42.7}, {8.9, 41.5}, {10.4, 40.7}, {11.9, 39.9}, {13.4, 38.9}, {14.8, 37.9}, {16.4, 36.9}, {18.2, 36.1}, {20.3, 35.4}, {22.2, 35.}, {24.2, 34.4}, {26.2, 33.9}, {28.1, 33.5}, {29.4, 33.5}, {30.3, 33.6}, {31., 33.6}, {31.4, 33.5}, {31.4, 33.8}, {31.3, 34.2}, {31.3, 34.4}, {31.3, 34.3}, {31.4, 34.3}, {31.4, 34.4}, {31.7, 34.5}, {31.9, 34.5}, {32.3, 34.6}, {32.5, 34.8}, {32.5, 34.9}, {31.9, 34.3}, {31.9, 34.4}, {31.7, 33.9}, {31.2, 32.6}, {30.7, 32.6}, {31., 33.1}, {30.8, 33.}, {30.9, 33.4}, {31., 34.1}, {31.8, 34.7}, {32.4, 34.7}, {34., 34.7}, {35.23, 34.7}, {36.49, 35.}, {37.41, 34.7}, {38.11, 34.5}, {39.18, 34.}, {40.1, 33.3}, {41.11, 32.4}, {41.9, 31.3}, {42.17, 30.8}, {41.8, 29.1}, {42.29, 27.6}, {42.91, 26.1}, {43.96, 24.6}, {45.509, 23.8}, {47.25, 23.7}, {48.81, 23.8}, {49.07, 24.2}, {48.48, 24.2}, {48.91, 24.9}, {49.3, 24.9}, {49.58, 24.5}, {49.77, 24.}, {49.66, 24.1}, {49.69, 24.4}, {49.66, 24.1}, {49.48, 24.1}, {49.38, 23.9}, {49.6, 23.5}, {49.26, 23.4}, {48.57, 23.4}, {48.09, 23.2}, {47.79, 23.2}, {48.02, 23.3}, {48.14, 22.7}, {48.69, 22.3}, {49.98, 21.9}, {51.66, 21.4}, {53.27, 20.5}, {54.6, 19.2}, {55.6, 17.7}, {56.9, 15.5}, {57.1, 13.9}, {57.1, 12.3}, {56.2, 10.8}, {55.3, 9.43}, {54.42, 8.08}, {53.57, 7.02}, {52.77, 6.04}, {52.2, 5.1}, {52.04, 4.47}, {52.34, 4.48}, {52.82, 4.91}, {53.3, 5.05}, {53.14, 4.65}, {52.22, 3.93}, {51.05, 3.03}, {49.92, 2.5}, {49.56, 2.45}, {49.96, 2.32}, {49.42, 2.12}, {48.5, 2.}, {47.5, 1.88}, {46.85, 1.83}, {46.5, 1.5}, {46.18, 0.945}, {45.995, -0.168}, {46.03, -0.836}, {46.42, -1.63}, {46.14, -2.63}, {46.2, -3.64}, {46.21, -4.54}, {46.27, -5.42}, {46.31, -6.42}, {45.693, -6.75}, {45.621, -6.86}, {45.987, -6.78}, {45.876, -6.71}, {45.916, -6.89}, {45.843, -6.94}, {45.773, -6.89}, {45.51, -6.79}, {45.302, -7.6}, {44.9036, -8.33}, {44.584, -9.22}, {44.383, -10.4}, {44.5, -11.6}, {44.843, -12.9}, {45.363, -13.9}, {45.812, -15.1}, {45.0297, -16.1}, {44.743, -16.5}, {44.527, -17.3}, {44.645, -17.8}, {44.391, -17.6}, {43.59, -17.8}, {43.4, -17.9}, {43.76, -18.1}, {44.398, -18.4}, {43.71, -18.4}, {43.25, -18.1}, {43.44, -17.6}, {43.44, -17.4}, {43.75, -17.6}, {44.414, -18.}, {45.01, -18.4}, {44.9159, -18.2}, {44.9764, -17.9}, {44.765, -18.}, {45.225, -18.4}, {45.799, -18.3}, {45.561, -18.2}, {45.517, -18.1}, {45.624, -18.5}, {46.27, -19.}, {47.12, -19.7}, {47.3, -20.4}, {46.89, -20.9}, {46.47, -21.1}, {46.38, -21.4}, {46.68, -21.8}, {47.09, -22.3}, {47.78, -23.1}, {47.65, -23.8}, {48.47, -24.9}, {48.47, -26.1}, {46.89, -26.9}, {45.588, -28.2}, {44.314, -29.7}, {43.32, -31.}, {42.57, -32.3}, {41.82, -34.}, {40.88, -35.1}, {40.09, -35.8}, {39.26, -36.2}, {38.47, -36.3}, {38.02, -36.6}, {37.82, -36.8}, {38.16, -37.5}, {38.31, -37.4}, {38.26, -37.6}, {37.94, -37.6}, {37.6, -37.6}, {37.04, -37.6}, {36.54, -37.6}, {36.45, -37.6}, {36.58, -37.6}, {36.21, -37.6}, {35.67, -38.}, {34.7, -37.7}, {34.4, -38.1}, {34.1, -38.5}, {33.8, -38.8}, {33.5, -38.6}, {33.2, -38.6}, {32.9, -38.7}, {32.8, -39.1}, {32.7, -39.6}, {32.7, -39.8}, {33.3, -39.4}, {34., -38.9}, {34.6, -38.6}, {35.23, -38.9}, {35.77, -39.6}, {36.35, -40.5}, {36.66, -40.3}, {36.52, -39.8}, {36.76, -39.4}, {36.1, -39.5}, {36.07, -40.2}, {36.52, -40.6}, {35.82, -40.4}, {35.67, -41.}, {35.31, -41.1}, {35.13, -41.7}, {35.05, -42.2}, {35.13, -42.3}, {35., -42.}, {34.8, -41.8}, {34.7, -42.2}, {34.6, -42.4}, {34.7, -42.7}, {35.19, -42.9}, {34.8, -42.5}, {34.4, -42.4}, {34.3, -42.5}, {33.7, -43.}, {33., -43.}, {32.3, -43.3}, {31.2, -43.6}, {29.5, -43.4}, {27.7, -43.5}, {26.4, -43.2}, {25., -42.8}, {23.5, -42.4}, {21.9, -41.8}, {20.5, -40.7}, {20., -39.5}, {19.1, -37.7}, {18.6, -35.6}, {18.1, -33.3}, {17.8, -30.9}, {17.8, -28.6}, {18.1, -26.6}, {18.6, -24.7}, {19.5, -23.3}, {20.4, -21.5}, {21.2, -19.8}, {22., -18.2}, {22.8, -16.5}, {23.7, -15.}, {24.8, -13.4}, {25.7, -11.9}, {26.1, -10.2}, {26.1, -8.62}, {25.9, -6.98}, {25.2, -5.34}, {24.8, -4.12}, {24.6, -2.98}, {24.2, -1.82}, {23.6, -1.01}, {23.1, -0.213}, {23.2, 0.896}, {23.5, 1.87}, {24.1, 2.92}, {24.5, 4.4}, {24.9, 6.06}, {25.5, 7.76}, {26.4, 9.48}, {27.3, 10.9}, {28.2, 12.4}, {28.8, 14.1}, {29.4, 15.9}, {29.7, 17.7}, {30., 19.5}, {30.4, 21.3}, {31., 23.}, {31.7, 24.7}, {32.3, 26.3}, {32.4, 27.5}, {32.4, 28.6}, {32.1, 29.5}, {31.5, 30.2}, {31.5, 30.9}, {31.9, 31.6}, {32.2, 32.}, {32., 31.7}, {32., 31.7}, {32.1, 31.6}, {32., 32.}, {32.3, 32.4}, {32.3, 32.3}, {32.2, 32.}, {32.2, 32.}, {32.2, 32.}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {31.8, 32.3}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.8}, {32.3, 31.9}, {32., 32.2}, {32., 32.2}, {32., 32.2}, {32., 32.1}, {32., 32.2}, {32., 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {31.8, 32.1}, {31.8, 32.2}, {31.8, 32.2}, {31.8, 32.2}, {31.8, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.1}, {31.9, 32.1}, {31.9, 32.1}, {31.8, 32.1}, {31.8, 32.1}, {31.8, 32.1}, {31.8, 32.1}, {31.8, 32.1}, {31.7, 32.2}, {31.6, 32.1}, {31.6, 32.1}, {31.6, 32.1}, {31.6, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.7}, {31.9, 32.7}, {31.9, 32.8}, {31.9, 32.8}, {31.9, 32.8}, {31.9, 32.7}, {31.9, 32.7}, {31.8, 32.6}, {31.8, 32.6}, {31.8, 32.6}, {31.8, 32.6}, {31.8, 32.6}, {31.8, 32.6}, {31.8, 32.7}, {31.9, 32.7}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.3}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {31.9, 32.4}, {32., 32.4}, {32., 32.5}, {32., 32.4}, {32., 32.5}, {32., 32.5}, {32., 32.5}, {32., 32.5}, {32., 32.5}, {32., 32.4}, {32., 32.4}, {32., 32.3}, {32.2, 32.5}, {32.2, 32.5}, {32.3, 32.5}, {32.3, 32.5}, {32.3, 32.5}, {32.3, 32.4}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.4}, {32.3, 32.4}, {32.4, 32.4}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.5, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.6}, {32.5, 32.5}, {32.5, 32.5}, {32.5, 32.5}, {32.6, 32.1}, {32.6, 32.1}, {32.5, 32.5}, {32.5, 32.5}, {32.5, 32.6}, {32.5, 32.6}, {32.5, 32.6}, {32.5, 32.7}, {32.6, 32.7}, {32.6, 32.7}, {32.6, 32.7}, {32.6, 32.7}, {32.6, 32.7}, {32.6, 32.6}, {32.5, 32.7}, {32.7, 32.8}, {32.7, 32.8}, {32.7, 32.8}, {33.1, 32.6}, {33., 32.6}, {33.1, 32.6}, {33.1, 32.7}, {33.1, 32.7}, {33.1, 32.7}, {33., 32.8}, {32.9, 32.7}, {32.6, 32.3}, {32.5, 32.3}, {32.5, 32.3}, {32.4, 32.3}, {32.4, 32.2}, {32.4, 32.2}, {32.4, 32.2}, {32.4, 32.2}, {32.4, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.2, 32.}, {32., 32.}, {31.8, 31.8}, {31.8, 31.8}, {31.8, 31.8}, {31.8, 31.9}, {31.8, 31.9}, {31.8, 31.9}, {31.8, 31.9}, {32.2, 32.2}, {32.2, 32.2}, {32.2, 32.4}, {32.2, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32., 32.6}, {31.9, 32.5}, {32.3, 32.6}, {32.3, 32.6}, {32.4, 32.7}, {32.2, 33.}, {32.2, 32.9}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.6, 32.6}, {32.6, 32.4}, {32.6, 32.4}, {32.8, 32.4}, {33.1, 32.4}, {33.1, 32.4}, {33.3, 32.4}, {33.4, 32.5}, {33.2, 32.3}, {33.4, 32.3}, {33.4, 32.3}, {33.8, 32.1}, {33.8, 32.2}, {33.9, 32.1}, {34.1, 32.4}, {34., 32.6}, {34., 32.6}, {34.2, 32.5}, {34.5, 32.3}, {35., 31.4}, {35.15, 31.}, {35.71, 30.6}, {35.87, 30.4}, {35.26, 30.9}, {34.6, 31.2}, {34.5, 31.5}, {34.6, 31.7}, {34.7, 31.7}, {34.8, 31.2}, {34.8, 30.6}, {34.7, 30.1}, {34.8, 29.9}, {34.9, 29.8}, {34.7, 30.1}, {34.1, 30.6}, {33.9, 31.2}, {33., 31.7}, {32.6, 31.8}, {32.1, 31.5}, {31.7, 31.4}, {31.8, 31.5}, {32., 31.9}, {32.4, 32.1}, {32.3, 32.3}, {32.3, 32.3}, {32.3, 32.3}, {32.3, 32.}, {32.2, 32.}, {32.2, 32.}, {32.2, 32.}, {32.3, 32.}, {32.1, 31.9}, {31.7, 31.9}, {31.3, 32.}, {30.8, 32.1}, {30.3, 32.3}, {29.7, 32.5}, {29.2, 32.8}, {28.6, 33.2}, {28.1, 33.7}, {27.5, 34.3}, {27., 34.9}, {26.7, 35.5}, {26.4, 36.1}, {26.1, 36.3}, {26., 36.6}, {26.2, 37.2}, {26.7, 37.5}, {27.4, 37.6}, {28., 37.}, {28.9, 36.9}, {29.7, 36.7}, {29.6, 36.}, {28.7, 35.1}, {27.6, 34.6}, {27., 34.6}, {26.7, 34.7}, {26.6, 34.6}, {26.7, 34.7}, {26.7, 35.1}, {26.6, 35.4}, {26.6, 35.2}, {26.7, 34.6}, {27., 34.1}, {27.5, 33.7}, {28.2, 33.4}, {29.1, 33.2}, {29.7, 32.9}, {30.3, 32.7}, {30.4, 32.7}, {30.4, 32.7}, {30.6, 32.6}, {31.1, 32.5}, {31.1, 32.4}, {31.1, 32.5}, {31.2, 32.7}, {31.4, 32.7}, {32., 32.8}, {32.2, 33.2}, {32.4, 33.3}, {32.5, 33.3}, {32.4, 33.3}, {32.4, 33.3}, {32.4, 32.8}, {32.3, 32.6}, {32.3, 32.6}, {32.3, 33.1}, {32.4, 32.7}, {32.4, 32.7}, {32.5, 32.5}, {32.6, 32.4}, {32.6, 32.4}, {32.6, 32.3}, {32.4, 32.5}, {32.3, 32.5}, {32.2, 32.5}, {32.2, 32.5}, {32.2, 32.5}, {32.3, 32.5}, {32.2, 32.5}, {32.2, 32.4}, {32.2, 32.4}, {32.2, 32.4}, {32.1, 32.4}, {32.1, 32.4}, {32.1, 32.4}, {32.1, 32.4}, {32.1, 32.4}, {32., 32.4}, {32., 32.2}, {32., 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {31.9, 32.2}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.1}, {32.1, 32.2}, {32.1, 32.3}, {32., 32.2}, {32., 32.2}, {32., 32.2}, {32.1, 32.3}, {32., 32.6}, {32., 32.6}, {32., 32.6}, {32., 32.6}, {32., 32.7}, {32.1, 32.8}, {32.1, 32.7}, {32.1, 32.8}, {32.2, 32.8}, {32.4, 32.8}, {32.4, 32.7}, {32.5, 32.8}, {32.5, 32.8}, {32.6, 32.9}, {32.6, 32.9}, {32.7, 32.7}, {32.7, 32.5}, {32.6, 32.4}, {32.6, 31.9}, {33.8, 30.5}, {34.2, 30.}, {34.6, 29.6}, {35.09, 29.3}, {35.85, 29.2}, {36.68, 29.}, {37.52, 29.}, {38.18, 29.1}, {38.89, 29.3}, {40.05, 30.}, {40.84, 29.8}, {41.62, 29.8}, {42.07, 29.2}, {42.35, 28.4}, {42.82, 27.6}, {43.93, 27.}, {45.559, 26.7}, {46.91, 26.2}, {48.06, 25.3}, {48.04, 24.5}, {48.19, 23.8}, {48.45, 23.6}, {49.02, 23.8}, {49.56, 23.2}, {49.92, 23.3}, {50.6, 23.6}, {49.92, 23.8}, {49.63, 23.2}, {49.49, 22.2}, {49.65, 21.}, {50.83, 19.6}, {51.24, 17.6}, {51.9, 15.6}, {52.45, 13.6}, {52.71, 11.4}, {52.71, 9.06}, {52.58, 6.91}, {52.24, 5.03}, {51.82, 3.6}, {51.56, 2.91}, {51.39, 2.81}, {51.15, 2.87}, {51.01, 2.64}, {50.81, 2.41}, {50.56, 1.78}, {50.35, 1.38}, {49.86, 1.29}, {49.33, 1.1}, {48.66, 0.792}, {48.05, 0.0841}, {47.79, -0.21}, {48.17, -0.465}, {47.43, -0.624}, {46.71, -1.04}, {46.14, -1.55}, {45.617, -1.89}, {45.455, -2.15}, {45.476, -2.32}, {45.474, -2.31}, {45.603, -2.87}, {45.511, -3.79}, {45.367, -4.6}, {44.9692, -5.47}, {44.584, -6.43}, {44.272, -7.44}, {44.286, -8.56}, {44.572, -9.58}, {44.576, -10.5}, {44.614, -10.6}, {44.491, -10.7}, {44.541, -10.8}, {45.0129, -11.}, {45.73, -11.2}, {46.7, -11.3}, {46.97, -11.5}, {46.85, -11.6}, {47.25, -11.4}, {46.97, -11.1}, {47.01, -10.7}, {46.97, -10.9}, {46.97, -10.9}, {46.45, -10.7}, {46.1, -10.7}, {45.753, -10.8}, {45.393, -11.1}, {45.323, -11.3}, {45.41, -11.6}, {45.186, -11.9}, {44.9381, -12.6}, {44.698, -13.7}, {44.446, -15.1}, {43.92, -16.9}, {42.82, -18.3}, {41.57, -20.2}, {40.24, -22.3}, {38.58, -24.4}, {37.13, -25.7}, {35.56, -26.4}, {34.2, -26.8}, {32.9, -26.7}, {31.7, -26.}, {30.7, -25.}, {29.9, -23.2}, {29.2, -21.8}, {28.7, -20.4}, {28., -18.7}, {27.5, -16.9}, {26.8, -15.}, {26.2, -13.}, {25.5, -10.9}, {24.6, -8.87}, {23.7, -7.02}, {22.9, -5.49}, {21.8, -4.49}, {20.9, -3.73}, {20.1, -2.77}, {19.1, -1.6}, {17.9, -0.41}, {16.6, 0.572}, {15.4, 1.13}, {14.4, 1.91}, {13.6, 2.96}, {12.9, 4.11}, {12.2, 5.4}, {11.4, 6.78}, {10.4, 8.}, {9.1, 9.16}, {7.8, 10.3}, {6.5, 11.6}, {5.4, 13.}, {4.5, 14.5}, {3.8, 15.9}, {2.9, 17.}, {2., 18.}, {1.2, 19.3}, {0.7, 20.8}, {0.7, 22.2}, {0.9, 23.8}, {1.3, 25.6}, {1.7, 27.4}, {1.8, 29.}, {1.8, 30.7}, {1.6, 32.4}, {1.3, 34.3}, {0.7, 36.1}, {0.1, 38.1}, {-0.4, 39.8}, {-0.7, 41.1}, {-1., 42.3}, {-1., 43.6}, {-0.8, 44.}, {-0.9, 44.6}, {-0.9, 45.}, {-0.5, 45.9}, {-0.4, 45.8}, {-0.3, 45.5}, {-0.2, 45.3}, {-0.1, 45.5}, {-0.1, 45.7}, {-0.2, 45.9}, {-0.3, 45.9}, {-0.3, 45.8}, {-0.1, 45.9}, {-0.1, 45.7}, {-0.2, 45.3}, {-0.5, 44.9}, {-0.7, 44.8}, {-1.4, 44.4}, {-2., 44.4}, {-2.9, 44.1}, {-4., 43.8}, {-5.1, 43.8}, {-6.3, 44.}, {-7.5, 44.}, {-8.8, 43.7}, {-10.2, 43.6}, {-11.4, 41.7}, {-12.7, 40.9}, {-13.9, 40.4}, {-15., 40.1}, {-16.3, 40.1}, {-17.5, 40.1}, {-18.7, 40.1}, {-20., 40.}, {-21.2, 39.8}, {-22.2, 39.6}, {-23.2, 39.4}, {-23., 39.7}, {-23.3, 39.8}, {-23.3, 39.7}, {-23.3, 39.7}, {-23.7, 39.4}, {-24.1, 38.5}, {-25.1, 37.2}, {-26.3, 36.3}, {-27.5, 35.6}, {-28.6, 34.7}, {-29.8, 33.8}, {-30.8, 33.4}, {-31.7, 32.9}, {-31.9, 32.5}, {-32., 32.5}, {-32., 32.7}, {-32.1, 32.5}, {-32.3, 32.6}, {-32.2, 32.7}, {-32.2, 32.8}, {-32.2, 32.6}, {-32.2, 32.3}, {-32.6, 32.2}, {-32.7, 32.2}, {-32.9, 32.}, {-33., 32.}, {-33., 31.8}, {-33.1, 31.3}, {-33.1, 31.}, {-33.3, 30.1}, {-33.5, 29.8}, {-33.8, 29.}, {-34.2, 28.2}, {-34.7, 27.1}, {-35.2, 25.9}, {-36., 24.7}, {-36.8, 23.5}, {-37.4, 22.3}, {-37.8, 20.9}, {-38.1, 19.4}, {-38.6, 17.8}, {-38.9, 16.5}, {-39.1, 15.2}, {-39., 14.1}, {-38.7, 13.}, {-38.5, 11.9}, {-38.2, 11.1}, {-38.1, 10.4}, {-38.3, 9.82}, {-38.8, 9.17}, {-39.6, 8.53}, {-40.4, 7.89}, {-41.2, 7.28}, {-41.9, 6.6}, {-42.6, 5.85}, {-43.2, 4.93}, {-43.6, 4.37}, {-43.8, 3.82}, {-43.9, 3.23}, {-44.3, 2.57}, {-44.6, 1.94}, {-45., 1.36}, {-45.3, 0.912}, {-45.6, 0.711}, {-45.9, 0.636}, {-46.1, 0.563}, {-46.1, 0.576}, {-46.1, 0.561}, {-46.2, 0.382}, {-45.9, -0.2}, {-45.8, -0.269}, {-45.8, -0.392}, {-45.8, -0.631}, {-45.9, -0.495}, {-45.6, -1.19}, {-45.7, -2.07}, {-45.7, -2.71}, {-45.7, -3.13}, {-45.7, -3.44}, {-45.6, -3.67}, {-45.7, -4.13}, {-45.9, -4.94}, {-46.4, -5.56}, {-46.7, -5.9}, {-46.5, -5.49}, {-46.3, -5.17}, {-46.2, -5.44}, {-46.5, -6.27}, {-47.2, -6.43}, {-47.6, -6.75}, {-47.7, -6.44}, {-48., -6.19}, {-48.2, -5.86}, {-49., -5.64}, {-50.1, -5.47}, {-51.2, -5.27}, {-51.8, -4.75}, {-51.7, -4.14}, {-51.3, -3.28}, {-50.9, -2.56}, {-50.5, -2.}, {-50.4, -2.03}, {-50.4, -1.63}, {-50.7, -1.11}, {-50.6, -0.458}, {-50.7, 0.421}, {-50.5, 1.18}, {-50.9, 1.89}, {-51.1, 2.74}, {-51.3, 3.61}, {-51.3, 4.38}, {-51.2, 5.67}, {-50.7, 7.96}, {-49.8, 9.4}, {-48.5, 10.6}, {-46.7, 11.2}, {-45.2, 12.1}, {-43.7, 13.}, {-42.3, 14.4}, {-41.3, 16.}, {-40.2, 17.8}, {-39.1, 19.8}, {-38.1, 21.8}, {-37.1, 23.5}, {-36.4, 25.}, {-35.9, 26.2}, {-36., 27.4}, {-35.4, 28.6}, {-34.5, 29.5}, {-34.4, 30.6}, {-34.7, 31.2}, {-34.8, 31.4}, {-35.1, 31.5}, {-35.2, 31.4}, {-35.1, 31.5}, {-34.5, 31.4}, {-34.1, 31.2}, {-34.3, 30.8}, {-35., 30.6}, {-36.1, 30.7}, {-36.7, 31.4}, {-36.4, 32.3}, {-35.5, 33.3}, {-34.8, 34.6}, {-34., 35.9}, {-33.2, 37.1}, {-31.8, 38.4}, {-30.1, 39.8}, {-28.3, 41.}, {-26.5, 42.6}, {-24.6, 44.1}, {-22.9, 45.7}, {-21.3, 47.4}, {-19.8, 48.8}, {-18.3, 50.5}, {-16.9, 51.7}, {-15.6, 52.9}, {-14.5, 54.}, {-13.4, 54.6}, {-12.7, 54.7}, {-11.4, 52.9}, {-10., 50.7}, {-9.1, 48.6}, {-7.4, 47.}, {-7.1, 46.6}, {-7.5, 46.9}, {-8., 47.2}, {-8.5, 47.9}, {-8.9, 48.5}, {-9.6, 48.8}, {-10.8, 48.6}, {-12.4, 48.1}, {-13.6, 47.3}, {-14.8, 46.4}, {-15.9, 45.8}, {-17.1, 45.}, {-18.5, 44.2}, {-19.9, 43.4}, {-21.3, 42.5}, {-22.5, 41.6}, {-23.6, 40.7}, {-24.9, 39.7}, {-26.2, 38.7}, {-27.6, 37.7}, {-28.7, 37.}, {-29.4, 36.5}, {-30.1, 36.}, {-30.4, 35.9}, {-30.8, 35.8}, {-31.3, 35.7}, {-31.9, 35.5}, {-32.2, 35.}, {-32.3, 34.6}, {-32.4, 34.2}, {-32.6, 34.2}, {-33., 34.3}, {-33.1, 34.1}, {-33.3, 34.5}, {-33.1, 34.1}, {-33.2, 34.1}, {-33.4, 33.8}, {-33.4, 33.8}, {-33.4, 33.8}, {-33.4, 33.9}, {-33.5, 33.9}, {-33.5, 33.9}, {-33.5, 33.9}, {-33.5, 34.}, {-33.4, 34.1}, {-33.4, 34.1}, {-33.5, 34.2}, {-33.4, 34.3}, {-33.5, 34.3}, {-33.5, 34.3}, {-33.5, 34.4}, {-33.5, 34.4}, {-33.6, 34.4}, {-33.6, 34.5}, {-33.7, 34.9}, {-33.7, 35.}, {-33.8, 34.9}, {-33.8, 34.9}, {-33.9, 35.}, {-33.9, 35.}, {-34., 35.2}, {-34., 35.2}, {-34., 35.2}, {-34., 35.1}, {-34., 35.2}, {-34.1, 35.2}, {-34.2, 35.2}, {-34.2, 35.3}, {-34.2, 35.3}, {-34.2, 35.3}, {-34.2, 35.3}, {-34.2, 35.3}, {-34.2, 35.3}, {-34.2, 35.3}, {-34.2, 35.4}, {-34.2, 35.4}, {-34.2, 35.4}, {-34.2, 35.4}, {-34.2, 35.4}, {-34.2, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.4}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.2, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34.3, 35.5}, {-34., 36.1}, {-34.2, 35.8}, {-34.2, 35.9}, {-34.2, 35.9}, {-34.2, 35.9}, {-34.2, 35.9}, {-34.4, 36.}, {-34.4, 36.1}, {-34.3, 36.1}, {-34.2, 36.1}, {-34.2, 36.2}, {-34.3, 36.2}, {-34.3, 36.3}, {-34.1, 36.5}, {-34.1, 36.5}, {-34.1, 36.5}, {-34.1, 36.6}, {-34.1, 36.6}, {-34.1, 36.6}, {-34., 36.6}, {-34., 36.6}, {-33.9, 36.3}, {-33.8, 36.4}, {-33.8, 36.4}, {-33.8, 36.4}, {-33.6, 36.5}, {-33.6, 36.6}, {-33.6, 36.6}, {-33.5, 36.6}, {-33.5, 36.6}, {-33.5, 36.7}, {-33.4, 36.8}, {-33.4, 36.9}, {-33.4, 36.9}, {-33.4, 36.9}, {-33.3, 37.}, {-33.3, 37.1}, {-33.2, 37.1}, {-33.2, 37.3}, {-33.1, 37.4}, {-33.1, 37.4}, {-33., 37.5}, {-32.9, 37.6}, {-32.9, 37.7}, {-32.9, 37.7}, {-32.9, 37.8}, {-32.9, 37.8}, {-32.7, 38.1}, {-32.7, 38.2}, {-32.6, 38.5}, {-32.6, 38.5}, {-32.6, 38.5}, {-32.6, 38.6}, {-32.6, 38.6}, {-32.6, 38.6}, {-32.6, 38.6}, {-32.6, 38.5}, {-32.6, 38.5}, {-32.6, 38.5}, {-32.6, 38.5}, {-32.5, 38.6}, {-32.5, 38.6}, {-32.8, 38.8}, {-32.2, 37.3}, {-32.4, 36.5}, {-31.8, 35.1}, {-31.2, 34.3}, {-30.6, 33.8}, {-29.3, 33.4}, {-28.4, 33.1}, {-27.4, 32.9}, {-26.4, 32.5}, {-25.3, 32.}, {-24.2, 31.3}, {-23.3, 30.2}, {-22.4, 29.}, {-21.2, 27.9}, {-19.7, 26.9}, {-17.9, 25.7}, {-16.2, 24.3}, {-14.8, 22.7}, {-13.4, 21.2}, {-12., 20.}, {-10.3, 19.2}, {-8.3, 19.2}, {-6.1, 19.}, {-4.1, 18.4}, {-2.3, 17.8}, {-0.4, 17.2}, {1.3, 16.6}, {3., 15.7}, {4.4, 15.3}, {5.8, 15.1}, {6.6, 15.}, {7.2, 14.3}, {8., 13.7}, {8.6, 12.8}, {9., 11.3}, {9.3, 9.68}, {9.6, 7.84}, {10.1, 6.17}, {11., 4.82}, {11.7, 3.73}, {11.8, 3.01}, {11.4, 2.57}, {11.2, 2.74}, {10.6, 2.64}, {10.3, 2.71}, {11., 2.7}, {11.8, 2.51}, {12.5, 2.28}, {13., 1.86}, {13., 1.52}, {13.3, 1.2}, {13., 0.752}, {12.9, 0.303}, {12.6, -0.419}, {12.3, -1.}, {11.9, -1.57}, {11.3, -1.63}, {11.5, -2.}, {12.1, -2.13}, {11.9, -2.13}, {11.5, -2.33}, {11., -2.65}, {10.6, -2.81}, {10.2, -3.31}, {9.8, -4.09}, {9.1, -4.63}, {8.7, -4.79}, {8.1, -4.95}, {7.4, -5.55}, {6.9, -5.53}, {6.9, -5.08}, {7.2, -5.29}, {7.8, -5.65}, {7.7, -5.86}, {7.1, -6.1}, {5.8, -6.08}, {5.2, -6.3}, {4.4, -6.39}, {3.3, -6.62}, {2., -7.1}, {1.2, -7.33}, {1., -7.89}, {0.5, -8.12}, {0.2, -8.45}, {-0.1, -8.75}, {-0.2, -8.71}, {-0.5, -8.75}, {-0.8, -8.79}, {-1.1, -9.04}, {-1.4, -9.32}, {-2., -9.77}, {-2.7, -9.74}, {-3.1, -9.64}, {-2.9, -9.31}, {-3.4, -8.65}, {-3.7, -7.85}, {-3.9, -6.83}, {-4.2, -5.36}, {-4.3, -4.62}, {-4.5, -3.91}, {-4.8, -2.86}, {-5., -1.71}, {-4.9, -0.421}, {-4.5, 1.02}, {-3.5, 2.44}, {-2.2, 3.85}, {-0.5, 5.41}, {1.3, 6.95}, {3.1, 8.53}, {5.1, 9.96}, {7.5, 11.}, {9.6, 12.}, {11.7, 12.9}, {13.9, 13.7}, {16.3, 14.4}, {18.3, 14.8}, {20.5, 15.}, {22.4, 14.7}, {45.819, -0.0124}}};
```

Comment: How do you define density?

Comment: I'm still collecting data so the density will change, so I need something dynamic. Ultimately I'm interested in creating a representative image. As for right now, completely dense could be 30 positions per area unit in a 1x1 square, a list 10 times longer, 300 positions will give the same density.

Comment: Yes, this is a very similar problem to mine. I will try to adapt the solution there for my needs, thank you.